# String contains

Tags: java, string

How to check if a string contains a specific character .
I have a string like 1244445g or 1234G555 or 1234566R or R1234556 i want to check if the string has g/G or R/r ,how to check this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you even looked at the javadoc for java.lang.String?

Comment: Are we expected to teach java basics?

Comment: you got so many responses .. wouldn't you accept one as answer ?

Answer (score 4):

With this kind of things, the best approach is to check the javadoc for the class you are working with. In this case, it's String, so check out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Then look for a function that does the trick, such as, in this case, [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29). That will look for the first ocurrence of the char, so it will either return where it occurs, or a -1 if it's not found.

If you want to look for either upper or lower case, you may do that on the return of `toLowerCase()`, or you may look into regex.

Also, consider googling a bit or even checking out similar questions in stackoverflow for next time. You'll save everyone's time, including yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the Java Doc and find the methods that the string class is offering like

```
String.contains(CharSequence c)
```

[JAVA DOC: Class String - Contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Simply use

```
String s = "abcdg/Gefgh";
boolean b = s.contains("g/G");
```

to check whether the specified char sequence is included in the source string.

**EDIT:**

In case your are seeking one particular char (either in upper case or in lower case) you might do the same only twice:

```
c.contains("g");
c.contains("G");
```

Comment: I think he wants to check for capital or non capital g

Comment: @Miquel I think it will work for the search for chars as well ? see edit ..

Comment: sure, it will certainly work as well, I'm just being picky because of the length and complexity of `indexOf(char)` vs `contains(CharSequence)` which ends up being a regular `contains(String)` search and a little bit more costly. It probably makes no difference to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] strArr = {"1244445g","1234G555","1234566R","R1234556"};

for (String str in strArr) {
    if (str.contains("g") || str.contains("G") || str.contains("r") || str.contains("R")) {
        System.out.println(str + " : YES");
    } else {
        System.out.println(str + " : NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for it `contains()` method of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or you can use [Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

```
line.contains("g");
line.contains("G");
```

So and similar for `r` and `R`.

Comment: you are greping the sting "g/G" an not the string "g" or "G"